# Running soapui from JUnit

Tags: maven, junit, soapui

I'm getting an error - package com.eviware.soapui.tools does not exist, when I try to run my junit test from intellij using a maven command such as "mvn clean verify -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome -Dtags="API" -Dproperties=test.properties"

I'm using intellij and added the the soapui-5.2.1.jar file as a dependency to the project (File->Project Preferences->Modules->Add jar). The code to run is pretty straight forward:

```
SoapUITestCaseRunner runner = new SoapUITestCaseRunner();
                runner.setProjectFile(RESOURCE_FOLDER + "periodictable-
soapui-project.xml");
                runner.run();
```

Do I need to add any dependencies to the pom file to get it to run? At this stage all I have done is the above steps to add the jar and used the import below:
    import com.eviware.soapui.tools.SoapUITestCaseRunner;

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The import and code itself looks fine but try adding the below dependency to your POM file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
        <artifactId>soapui</artifactId>
        <version>X.X.X</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This dependency would download the SOAPUI jar(version of your choice, for me it works with v5.2.1) and allow you to execute the test suites inside your test project XML.

Comment: Seriously doubt this is going to work without also defining an external Smartbear repository.

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/junit/junit-integration.html) says:

> Copy all the jar files from the lib folder for SoapUI Pro Installation folder in class file path. Copy the soapui-pro-5.0.0.jar (or corresponding version) from the bin folder in SoapUI Pro intallation [sic] directory.

For the open-source version, the same instructions apply, you just copy the non-Pro resources.

If you already added the soapui-5.2.1.jar as a dependency to your project, you should be able to check that it was brought in with all of its dependencies correctly.